# Invalid meta links on the data.stackexchange.com site

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, meta, data-explorer

The following meta sites do not have valid links on https://data.stackexchange.com/

1. Seasoned Advice
2. Unix & Linux
3. Ask Different
4. Geographic Information Systems

They all point to `http://meta./`

I'm not sure if this is the place to put it or not but I couldn't find any other place that looked appropriate.

These links have been fixed, however, there are still broken links I've just located.

Ask Ubuntu meta points to `http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com` instead of `http://meta.askubuntu.com/` and the se site still points to old location too.

These links are missing - not sure if it's intentional or not

1. `http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/`
2. `http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/`
3. `http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/`
4. `http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/`
5. `http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/`

Comment: Yes, this is the correct place to have reported this. I don't think I've yet to see such an inquiry on a question where the answer would've been "no".

Comment: Heh, This is my first meta usage so I just wasn't sure :) Especially since I'm reporting a bug and not "asking a question". Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed a while back, all "visit site" links on the homepage should now point to the expected place.